# What's the relation between declare(ticks) and a signal handler in php

Tags: php, pcntl

I have some code like this, and I want to understand how does fork work, but I'm confused with  `declare(ticks=1)`.
when I put it in the first line, after the child process finished, the signal handler will be called, which is what I want; but when I remove it, the signal handler will never be called! So, I want to know how does the ticks influence the signal processing.

```
<?php
declare(ticks=1);
function sigHandler($signal)
{
    echo "a child exited\n";
}
pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, sigHandler, false);
echo "this is " . posix_getpid() . PHP_EOL;
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++)
{
    $pid = pcntl_fork();
    if($pid == -1) 
    {   
        echo 'fork failed ' . PHP_EOL;
    }   
    else if($pid)
    {   
    }   
    else
    {   
        $pid = posix_getpid();
        echo 'child ' . $pid . ' ' . time() . PHP_EOL;
        sleep(rand(2,5));
        echo 'child ' . $pid . ' done ' . time() . PHP_EOL;
        exit(0);
    }   
}
do
{
    $pid = pcntl_wait($status); 
    echo 'child quit ' . $pid . PHP_EOL;
}while($pid > 0); 
echo 'parent done' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Minor observation (quote the function name pls.):

```
pcntl_signal(SIGCHLD, 'sigHandler', false);
```

There are two different APIs involved.

- The pcntl_wait() call is blocking until it gets an notification from the kernel.
- The interrupt handling is an event loop inside the PHP interpreter.  This is a hack feature and as of PHP5.3, there is a better way to do it ~ pcntl_signal_dispatch().

  - **To answer to question, having *declare ticks* is like turning your mobile ringtone ON, or otherwise you never notice incoming calls.**
  - The PHP5.3 method is much better engineering, and alot more controllable.
  - The default signal handler for most signals is sigignore, which receives the interrupt and does nothing.  As you have registered the user handler I doubt this is being used.
  - I have never been able to discover the default value for the ticks, when not set directly.
  - Setting ticks to a small value does make scripts abit run slower, but you need to be doing heavy processing and monitoring to notice this.  It makes a less predictable execution cost, I guess due to copying things around in the stack.
  - Without *declare ticks* or pcntl_signal_dispatch(), the signal is never picked up. If you are writing simple webpages, which terminate quickly; this may be the most sensible policy.
  - *declare ticks* needs to be tested carefully, as it has confusing scope rules.  The safest method to put it at the head of your first script, like *use strict* in Perl.